# How does nested list-initialization forward its arguments?

Tags: c++11, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

In the initialization of a vector of pairs

```cpp
  std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> foo{{1.0, "one"}, {2.0, "two"}};
```

how am I supposed to interpret the construction of `foo`? As I understand it,

1. The constructor is called with braced initialization syntax so the overload `vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` is strongly preferred and selected
2. The template parameter of `std::initializer_list<T>` is deduced to `std::pair<int, std::string>`
3. Each element of `foo` is a `std::pair`. However, `std::pair` has no overload accepting `std::initializer_list`.

I am not so sure about step 3. I know the inner braces can't be interpreted as `std::initializer_list` since they are heterogenous. What mechanism in the standard is actually constructing each element of `foo`? I suspect the answer has something to do with forwarding the arguments in the inner braces to the overload `template< class U1, class U2 pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );` but I don't know what this is called.

**EDIT**:

I figure a simpler way to ask the same question would be: When one does

```cpp
std::map<int, std::string> m = { // nested list-initialization
           {1, "a"},
           {2, {'a', 'b', 'c'} },
           {3, s1}
```

as shown in [the cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), where in the standard does it say that `{1, "a"}`, `{2, {'a', 'b', 'c'} }`, and `{3, s1}` each get forwarded to the constructor for `std::pair<int, std::string>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, expressions are analyzed inside-out: The inner expressions have types and these types then decide which meaning the outer operators have and which functions are to be called.

But initializer lists are not expressions, and have no type. Therefore, inside-out does not work. Special overload resolution rules are needed to account for initializer lists.

The first rule is: If there are constructors with a single parameter that is some `initializer_list<T>`, then in a first round of overload resolution only such constructors are considered ([over.match.list](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match#list)).

The second rule is: For each `initializer_list<T>` candidate (there could be more than one of them per class, with different `T` each), it is checked that each initializer can be converted to `T`, and only those candidates remain where this works out ([over.ics.list](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/over.match#over.ics.list-5)).

This second rule is basically, where the initializer-lists-have-no-type hurdle is taken and inside-out analysis is resumed.

Once overload resolution has decided that a particular `initializer_list<T>` constructor should be used, copy-initialization is used to initialize the [elements of type `T` of the initializer](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-5) list.

Comment: Thanks. In the second rule you mentioned, if the first inner braces looked like `{1,"a"}`, then the compiler performs the equivalent of `T{1,"a"}` to see if the conversion is successful?

Comment: @segfault Yes, that's it.

Comment: Is there a name or a section of the standard that mentions this? There's plenty of examples for the simple case where uniform initialization is done like `Object{x,y,z}` but it's hard to find the nested case explicitly mentioned anywhere.

Comment: These rules are summarized in [Overload resolution on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution); rule 1 is in section "List-initialization", rule 2 is in section "Implicit conversion sequence in list-initialization". I've added references to the Standard wording to the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I’ve marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two different concepts:

**1) initializer lists**

**`initializer_list<T>`:** that is mainly used for initialization of collections. In this case, all of the members should be of the same type. (not applicable for `std::pair`)

Example:

`std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

**2) Uniform initialization**

**`Uniform initialization`**: in which the braces are used to construct and initialize some objects like structs, classes (with an appropriate constructor) and basic types (int, char, etc.).

Example:

```
struct X { int x; std::string s;}; 
X x{1, "Hi"}; // Not an initializer_list here.
```

Having mentioned that, for initialization of a `std::pair` with a brace initializer, you will need a constructor that takes two elements, i.e. the first and the second elements, not a `std::initializer_list<T>`. For example on my machine with VS2015 installed, this constructor looks like this:

```
template<class _Other1,
    class _Other2,
    class = enable_if_t<is_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>::value
                    && is_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2>::value>,
    enable_if_t<is_convertible<_Other1, _Ty1>::value
            && is_convertible<_Other2, _Ty2>::value, int> = 0>
    constexpr pair(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2) // -----> Here the constructor takes 2 input params
        _NOEXCEPT_OP((is_nothrow_constructible<_Ty1, _Other1>::value
            && is_nothrow_constructible<_Ty2, _Other2>::value))
    : first(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)), // ----> initialize the first 
            second(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2)) // ----> initialize the second
    {   // construct from moved values
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. However, what wasn’t clear to me was how/where the standard defines the evaluation of inner braced unit lists. Somehow the inner braces get used as arguments to the `std::pair` constructor you showed above. Before that constructor even gets invoked, does the standard say that `std::map<int, std::string> m = {{1, "a"}, {2, {'a', 'b', 'c'} }, {3, s1}}` gets converted to `std::map<int, std::string> m = {std::pair{1, "a"}, std::pair{2, {'a', 'b', 'c'} }, std::pair{3, s1}}`?

Comment: @segfault Your map implementation does that. In fact, `std::map<T1,T2>` has a constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list<std::pair<T1,T2>>` as the input parameter. When you pass a list of pairs to the map, this constructor creates a `std::pair`  for each object in the list. Then these pairs will be inserted into the map.